# “Yes” is absent in Windows 10 elevation dialog

Tags: windows, uac

When I try to do anything that needs elevated privileges in Windows 10 (such as run a program downloaded from Internet), I get the question

```
Do you want to allow this app to make changes to your PC?
```

but it has no `yes` option, only `no` button. This happened after I changed my account's type to user (it was administrator). However, for whatever reason, the laptop seems not to have any other administrator account, or it is not enabled. Commands like

```
net user administrator /active:yes
```

show the same dialog, without a `yes` button.

I tried substituting `SETHC.EXE` with `CMD.EXE` as [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1020273/yes-is-disabled-in-windows-10-elevation-dialog) recommends, and five times pressing `Shift` really brings a command prompt, but it does not have admin rights: it runs under the same user account.

Anything else I can try?

Comment: Once you've done the Sethc.exe you need to reboot and press shift before logging in.

Comment: "the laptop seems not to have any other administrator account" - If the machine does not have an active administrator then you will be unable to elevate an application's permissions above then what the user running the application has.  UAC is prompted on even Administrator accounts due to how Windows by default runs applications at the lowest permission. **Enable the built-in Administrator account.**  You will want to ask your IT Administrator to do that for you.

Comment: @Mokubai Yes, it worked! Could you please convert your comment into answer so that I could accept it?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, the whole question was about how to enable the administrator account. Now with the help of Mokubai I have used the SETHC.EXE trick to enable it.

Comment: BTW, on a non-English system the command `net user administrator /active:yes` should use a different name for "administrator". For example, on a Spanish system it is "administrador".

Comment: You didn't ask how to enable the built-in Administrator account.

Comment: @AlexanderGelbukh technically the answer was from the duplicate so I'd rather close as a duplicate. The answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/1020311/19943) mentions "when windows comes up" but does not explicitly mention rebooting or doing it on the login screen. I'm tempted to edit that step in...